# Better approach to store the async calls and execute it sequentially

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, task, quartz.net

I have a quartz job that runs once in 30 days in my ASP.NET application. The job loops through and passes the data to the API which in turn fetches JSON data. I am trying to store the data in a temporary table created in the MSSQL server using a stored procedure. But due to ~30 asynchronous requests the DB execution stops due to timeout error.

```
  class RunJob : Ijob{
    public void Execute
    {
      var start =1, end =100;
      for(i=start ; i<end;i++)
      {
        GetAsyncFunction(i);
      }
    }
    public async Task GetAsyncFunction(int i)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage res=  await client.GetAsync(url+"?param="i.ToString());
        if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode){
             //insert stringified json data to DB table
        }
    }
}
//call Execute() method in main
```

Is there a better approach to store the async calls and execute it sequentially. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't post any database code but the code is clearly wrong because the async calls are never awaited. Your code also leaks sockets. HttpClient is thread safe and meant to be reused. Right now you're firing off 100 concurrent tasks, creating 100 sockets. 100 concurrent requests to a database is *nothing at all*. Databases are built to handle hundreds or thousands of concurrent calls. Delays are caused by missing indexes and inefficient queries. In this case though, there are many other things that could also cause timeouts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code shows 100 concurrent async calls that are never awaited. There's no database code but 100 concurrent calls is nothing for SQL Server. The code contains serious errors and leaks though

- 100 calls are made to `GetAsyncFunction` but never awaited. This means 100 HTTP call *attempts* are made to the same server at the same time. There's a limit to how many concurrent calls can be made to the same endpoint, which is 2 in .NET Old (aka Framework).
- The remote service may not be able to handle 100 concurrent calls from the same client or may *throttle* them. All web servers (IIS, Apache, NGINX) put limits to ensure the server can handle high traffic without going down due to misbehaving clients
- 100 new HttpClient instances are created which results in 100 new sockets that never close. HttpClient is thread-safe and *meant* to be reused. Using a *single* HttpClient instance will only use as many sockets as needed
- There's no database code, but if it's similar to the network code, it probably means 100 connections are created but never closed, resulting in a 100-way lock conflict. INSERTs take locks on tables and indexes in *all* databases that aren't compatible with other similar locks.

Quartz.NET supports asynchronous execution methods. From the [Quick Start](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/quick-start.html#trying-out-the-application-and-adding-jobs) page:

```
public class HelloJob : IJob
{
    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("Greetings from HelloJob!");
    }
}
```

This alone allows executing the 100 requests sequentially:

```
class RunJob : Ijob
{
    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        var dataMap = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap;

        var start =1, end =100;
        var baseUrl= dataMap.GetString("url");
        var cns= dataMap.GetString("ConnectionString");

        using var client=new HttpClient();
        for(i=start ; i<end;i++)
        {
            var url=$"{baseUrl}?param={i}";
            await GetAsyncFunction(client,url,cns);
        }
    }
```

The `GetAsyncFunction` should just make the HTTP call and store the result. In this case I use [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) to reduce the ADO.NET boilerplate to a single call. Dapper creates a parameterized query using the supplied object properties *and* takes care of opening and closing the connection:

```
public async Task GetAsyncFunction(HttpClient client,string url, string cns)
{
    var sql="INSERT INTO SomeTable (Url,Json) VALUES (@url,@json)";
    try
    {
        var json=await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        using var cn=new SqlConnection(cns);
        await cn.Exequte(sql,new {url,json});
    }
    catch(HttpRequestException ex)
    {
        //Handle any HTTP errors
        ...
    }
    catch(Exception ...)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

This will execute the requests sequentially. To execute multiple requests concurrently without starting all tasks at once, you can use `Parallel.ForeachAsync` in .NET 6 or eg `ActionBlock` in previous versions to execute a specific number of requests at a time:

```
public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
    var dataMap = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap;

    var start =1, end =100;
    var baseUrl= dataMap.GetString("url");
    var cns= dataMap.GetString("ConnectionString");
    var dop=10;
    var urls=Enumerable.Range(start,end-start)
                       .Select(i=>$"{baseUrl}?param={i}");

    using var handler=new HttpClientHandler {
        MaxConnectionsPerServer =20
    };
    using var client=new HttpClient(handler);

    var dop = new ParallelOptions()
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = dop
    };

    await Parallel.ForEachAsync(range dop async (url,ct)=>{
        await GetAsyncFunction(client,url,cns);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you created a new connection to the database with each request, but didn't Dispose the connection after the request ended. Then the database will run out of her maximum database connection limit and start rejecting requests. Check if it is.

Comment: There's no database code in the question. 100 tasks are started at once and never awaited. 100 network connections are created because HttpClient isn't reused.